# use of break <br> in multidimentional array in php

Tags: php

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <br><br>
 <div id="panel1" style="height:500px;width:500px;border-style:solid;color:Blue;">
 <div id="top-panel" style="height:40px;width:495px;border-style:solid;color:lavender;"></div>
 <div id="mines" style="height:450px;width:495px;border-style:solid;color:lavender;">
 <?php
 $arr=array(array());
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
  for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
  {
   $arr[$i][$j]=0;
   if($j==9){
   echo "<button type='button' style='height:35px;width:35px;background-color:red;' name='<?php echo $i$j;?>' id='<?php echo $i$j;?>' />";
    echo "<br/>";
   }
   else
    {
    echo "<button type='button' style='height:35px;width:35px;background-color:Blue;' name='<?php echo $i.$j;?>' id='<?php echo $i$j;?>' />"; 
    }
  }
 }
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
  for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
  {
   $b=rand(1,10);
   $c=rand(1,10);
   $arr[$b][$c]=1;
  }
 } 
 ?>
 </div>
 </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

so the above is a simple code for a multidimensional array. here i am using "br" tag for creating a new line if  %J==9, means after column number reaches to 9. i did it in tables, its working. but in multidimentional array, it will not work. so how we can create a new line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your '<BR>' is getting caught inside the <BUTTON> tag (if you Inspect Element under chrome you'll see it, I added new lines to make it easier). Try including the explicit closing tag:

```
if($j==9){
    echo "<button type='button' style='height:35px;width:35px;background-color:red;' name='$i$j' id='$i$j' ></button>\n";
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

I removed the <?php echo ... ?> since you're already in PHP mode.

Comment: yes as u mentioned button tag is the problem. i didnot write end tag for button. after putting end tag its coming. thnkx.. and also no need of newline - n . br is working after end button tag. also i was in hurry , so didnot paid attention to <?php , as u told we r already in php mode. thnkx.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new `div` instead of `echo "<br/>";` use echo `"<div  style='clear:both'>&nbso or your content if you want to print some thing</div>";`

hope this will sure solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $arr=array(array());

     for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
     {
          for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
          {
               $arr[$i][$j]=0;
               if($j==9)
               {
                  echo "<button type='button' style='height:35px;width:35px;background-color:red;' name='".$i.$j."' id='".$i.$j."' ></button>";
                  echo "<br/>";
               }
               else
               {
                    echo "<button type='button' style='height:35px;width:35px;background-color:Blue;' name='".$i.$j."' id='".$i.$j."' ></button>"; 
               }
          }
     }
     for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
     {
          for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
          {
           $b=rand(1,10);
           $c=rand(1,10);
           $arr[$b][$c]=1;
          }
     } 
?>
```

you didn't close your `<button>` tag